# Python: how to use values of self inside of a class?

Tags: python, object, self

My current class:

```
class Animals(object):

   def __init__(self):
       self.dogs = list()
       self.cats = list()
       # a lot of species ...

   def add_animal(self, animal, category):
       if category == 'cats':
           self.cats.append(animal)
       if category == 'dogs':
           self.dogs.append(animal)
       # a lot of ifs here ...
```

I would like to create a universal add_animal method, something like:

```
def add_animal(self, animal, category):
    self[category].append(animal)
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You could use `getattr(self, category)`. I'd put the lists into a dictionary however; `self.categories = {'cats': [], 'dogs': []}`.

Comment: This seems like a weird approach in general. Why do you have to pass two arguments, rather than e.g. `if isinstance(animal, Cat)` (where `class Cat(Animal):`)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I'm trying to avoid using a giant **if isinstance(..)** statement. And I have got a lot of such methods in the class, so it will be problematic to change all them after every change of the categories.